# What is causing the error 'User lacks privilege or object not found: FieldName'

Tags: sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

Using a MS Access Database to hold my information, it has been working fine up and till this point i created a new method named **CreateLicense()** which takes in the license class i made and writes it to the database.

When the code is run it will spit out a error stating **'user lacks privilege or object not found: EXPIRED'**

Already tried changing the fields names of Expired incase it was a reserved word or something. Also tried removing the Expired field but then flags the same error but with **CONTACT** instead.

```
INSERT INTO Licenses (Name, DateRedeemed, Expired, LicenseLength, Contact) VALUES ('name','25/Jun/2019','02/Jul/2019','2','contact')
user lacks privilege or object not found: EXPIRED
```

Here is the output of my SQL statement
 This is the code

```java
public boolean CreateLicense(License newLicense) {
        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            File currentDir = new File(""); // Creates a new file
            String newFilePath = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + currentDir.getAbsolutePath().toString() + "\\store\\data\\database1.accdb";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(newFilePath);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Licenses (Name, DateRedeemed, Expired, LicenseLength, Contact) VALUES "
                    //Values for the SQL Statement
                    + "('" + newLicense.getName()//Start Line
                    + "','" + newLicense.getRedeemed()//Middle Lines
                    + "','" + newLicense.getExpired()//Middle Lines
                    + "','" + newLicense.getLicenseLength()//Middle Lines
                    + "','" + newLicense.getContact()+ "')");//End Line

            conn.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String message = ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Some additional information to help solve
The table name is **Licenses**
Field Names and their type

- ID - `Autonumber`
- Name - `String`
- DateRedeemed - `String`
- Expired - `String`
- LicenseLength- `int`
- Contact- `String`

**UPDATE**
I created a query using the query design in access, this supplied the information to the database fine, so it cant be the sql which is the issue.

**UPDATE**
When i rename the table in the database and run the application i get the same error but with the table name instead, i am going to create a new database and see if that solves anything

**Solution Found**

Comment: Please do not concatenate values into a SQL strings. Learn to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a pure moment of stupidity, i had a created a backup database which was saved just outside the fat jar directory, as when you create a fat jar it wipes the folder. At the some point i have opened that to test something forgotten to close and that is where i added the license table.

So when i run the application it actually couldn't find the table due to the file path, I figured this out by testing my other methods, i used my **createUser()** method which showed which database it was being written to.

For Other users

If you get this error, try the following

- Apply Joakim's solution if you are using one large SQL string like i was as it could be a issue with your SQL statement.(And its better programming practise)
- Look at your Table name and fields and make sure they are the exact same as your SQL
- Run your application and test another method where it was previously working, if successful check where the application has written the value
- If all else fails, delete the method, type it from scratch with no copy and paste, create a new database as i had this issue before when i used relationships between tables within my access database

I hope this solution helps others solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

LicenseLength is an Int but you are surrounding it with quotes like it is a string. Also, have you tried using a parameterized query like

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Licenses (Name, DateRedeemed, Expired, LicenseLength, Contact) VALUES (?, ? ,?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, newLicense.getName());
stmt.setString(2, newLicense.getRedeemed());
stmt.setString(3, newLicense.getExpired());
stmt.setInt(4, newLicense.getLicenseLength());
stmt.setString(5, newLicense.getContact());
```

Comment: I used the query design in sql and both quotes and without work fine, i also tried your solution and im getting an error of 'no suitable method for prepareStatement(no arguments) '

Comment: @RyanMacPhee typo on my part, the sql string should be the argument (Which you can see in the documentation). I update my answer

Comment: ohh after i typed it a realised i just didnt call the sql string

Comment: Tried it and it didn't seem to fix the issue,  Same error,  i am going to use this format for future db methods since this seems much more effective rather than trying to wright a full sql string. Thank you for that Joakim